# How can i display my accessor (instance array) using Java? Code included

Tags: java, accessor

Not able to print the toString method, would like to be able to print the accessor and am not sure what the issue is. Am I not storing the array as an instance properly? I'd like to access the array in future methods so it is important for it to be stored as an instance.

```
public class j {
    private double[] s;

    public j() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File in = new File("file.txt");
        Scanner inScanFile = new Scanner(in);

        int lines = inScanFile.nextInt();
        s = new double[lines];
    }

    public double getXintercept(){
        return s[2];
    }

    public String toString() {
        double c = getXintercept();
        System.out.println(c);
        String descrip = "";
        descrip = "kiki" + c; //want this to display and it won't
        return descrip;
    }
}
```

Comment: Go to source of Object class and check `toString()` method. Is it same as you have added in your class. Is your `toString` actually override method of Object's `toString`? Annotate your `toString` method with `@Override` and see whether it show any compilation error?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: The code compiles, but the method will not print when I run it.

Comment: Show the code that runs it.

Comment: import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class j
{
    double[] s;
    public j()throws FileNotFoundException{ 
        File in = new File("file.txt");
        Scanner inScanFile = new Scanner(in);
    
        int lines = inScanFile.nextInt();
        s = new double[lines];
     
      
   
    }

    public double getXintercept(){
        return s[2];
    }
    public String toString(){
    double c = getXintercept();
    System.out.println(c);
    String descrip = "";
    descrip = "kiki" + c;
    return descrip;
    }
}

Comment: the toString method won't print, the code compiles fine.

Comment: Lots of broken code compiles just fine. I asked how you're running the code. Where's the `main()`?

Comment: Oh, gotcha, kinda new to this.I don't have a main, this is the entire code.

Comment: I see. You might want to learn how to **run** programs, not just *compile* them. That's covered in every single basic tutorial.

Comment: This is funny, is it a good enough reason to upvote a question? I'm just going to do it.

Comment: The assignment explicitly didn't call for a main..and I get an error about  not being to call the toString in a static main method. Even without the static, nothing displays when I run the code.

Comment: So there's some sort of test harness that runs the code. Well, since we don't know what it's doing and how it tries to use your class, there's very little we can do for you. If you're not getting any output, it could be that your class isn't being used at all. Or it could be pretty much anything. Ask your teacher for help.

Comment: Created a test class and got it to display, I'm still not quite clear why it wouldn't run from the same class but I'll follow up with my teacher about that. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Create the object of this class in main method and then print the object using

```
System.out.println(yourobject);
```

Comment: I think he's going to need a lot more coaching than this, if he's never ran a Java program before.

Comment: that's exactly what I was thinking.